# UWP.C++ How to toggle Adaptive Brightness from BackgroudTask

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-mobile

now i have
[PointerTo.BrightnessOverride from MyBackgroudTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930447/uwp-c-create-task-with-parameter)

```
aaa_bo = BrightnessOverride::GetDefaultForSystem();// OK VStudio & Phone
```

I can Set Brightness from BackgroundTask.exe, but How can i toggle Adaptive Brightness ON / OFF ?

I created class NullObject, but still compile error

```
aa_OBJ_BO->SaveForSystemAsync(NullObject());
Error   C2664   'Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<bool> ^Windows::Graphics::Display::BrightnessOverride::SaveForSystemAsync(Windows::Graphics::Display::BrightnessOverride ^)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'BackgroundTask::NullObject' to 'Windows::Graphics::Display::BrightnessOverride ^'   BackgroundTask  554 1   Build   

private ref class ClsDummy {
        public:
            virtual ~ClsDummy() {};
            virtual void MakeSound() {};
    };
        //Windows::Graphics::Display::BrightnessOverride^
    private ref class NullObject sealed : public ClsDummy {
        public:
            //virtual void MakeSound() const override {};
        virtual void MakeSound() override {};
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [BrightnessOverride.SaveForSystemAsync(BrightnessOverride) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.brightnessoverride.saveforsystemasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-graphics-display-brightnessoverride-saveforsystemasync(windows-graphics-display-brightnessoverride)). The method mentioned that if a NULL object is passed in, the system turns on auto-brightness. So you might need to call this method with a null value to turn on the auto-brightness.

Comment: Hi, thx NULL Objects means  [Null_object_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)  ?

Comment: @Pacala_ba Yes, a null object as the parameter, if you don't set any parameter, it will give you an error.

Comment: @Pacala_ba does my solution work for you?

Comment: Hi Roy Li, it is not so easy for me, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#C++) , seems like i need create some class name = NULL_CLASS_NAME..

Comment: Hi Roy Li,  First step would be ,i need create some class name = NULL_CLASS_NAME.. in File Scenario1_BackgroundTask.h ? or in new file NULL_CLASS_NAME.h ?

Comment: Hi Roy Li, i am using Lumia 950, with Brightness=0 (to save Battery Life), but on Sunshine i see nothing... now i can with my Background Task switch Brightness to Max with ONLY Phone Orientation change, without any tap on Screen, Adaptive Brightness may be second optional solution

Comment: Hi Roy Li, Question updated..., but still no success

Comment: @Pacala_ba what's the device that you are using for testing? Is it a laptop that supports auto-brightness?